# Which PHPStan version to use to accomodate Symfony 2.8, phpstan-symfony and phpstan-doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, phpstan

I'm fixing a platform which uses Symfony 2.8, with the help of PHPStan (PHP 7.1).
I started with the last version of it (0.12.91), and it was great for the first two levels (0, 1).
Level 2 wants to check unknown methods calls, but does not understand - among others - repositories.
I've added phpstan-doctrine successfuly, but when it comes to phpstan-symfony, I get version conflicts with Symfony. I can't figure out the correct phpstan-symfony version to use, any clue?

Comment: As far as I can tell even the earliest release 0.10 seems to be created for Symfony 3.x/4.x and based on the date probably favored 4.x as it was already released.

Comment: I'd recommend upgrading the Symfony version as yours is really old and haven't been receiving bugfixes for 2.5 years: https://symfony.com/releases

Comment: @OndřejMirtes I wish I had the power to upgrade the Symfony version :-)
Thanks for your answers guys, I will ignore this type of errors for now 
`ignoreErrors:
    - '#Call to an undefined method#'`